# Laravel convierte archivos CSV a TXT automáticamente

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cuando subo un archivo en formato CSV (en este caso usando Angular(4)) Laravel (5.4) automáticamente lo convierte y almacena en formato TXT (obviamente es solo un cambio de extensión). Me surge esta pregunta porque recién estoy aprendiendo Laravel y no encuentro información al respecto.

¿Como puedo hacer para conservar el tipo CSV?

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
$path = $request->file('archivo')->store('archivos');
return response()->json([ "datos" => $path, "status" => true], 201);
```

Saludos.

Comment: Podrías poner algo de código para poder ayudarte de mejor forma, ya que laravel no hace esa conversión por si sola, el error puede estar en tu codigo.

Comment: Ok he añadido el código que uso para hacerlo. Gracias.